# How to emit event not earlier than in specified timeout in RXJS?

Tags: rxjs, system.reactive

I want to emit event after visual effects passed off. Visual effects last 5 seconds.
This code works but I think there is a better solution:

```
Observable.combineLatest(observable1, Observable.of('hold').delay(5000)).subscribe(() => {
    alert('ok');
});
```

This event should be fired when observable1 is fired but not earlier than 5 seconds. (If observable1 fired after 6 seconds then this event should be fired after 6 seconds. If observable1 fired after 3 seconds then this event should be fired after 5 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
observable1.combineLatest(Observable.timer(5000))
    subscribe(([result]) => {
        alert('ok');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

What you describe looks like you need [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom) which emits only when it's source emits:

```
Observable
  .of('hold')
  .delay(5000)
  .withLatestFrom(observable1, (...values) => values[1])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Only the delayed `'hold'` string controls when this operator emits the latest value from `Observable1`. The operator doesn't emit anything until both its source and `Observable1` emit so even if `Observable1` emits after eg. `6s` you'll receive the first item after `6s`. When it's the other way around and `Observable1` emits earlier it'll wait for the `'hold'` string.

If you're not interested in the value from `Observable1` you can ignore the projection function and use just:

```
...
.withLatestFrom(observable1)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for not being an RxJS coder - I code in C#. Here's how to do this in C#:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    Observable
        .Merge(
            observable1.Take(1).Select(x => "hold"),
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6.0)).Select(x => "hold"))
        .Skip(1);
```

Now, I can test this like this:

```
var observable1 = new Subject<long>();

IObservable<string> query =
    Observable
        .Merge(
            observable1.Take(1).Select(x => "hold"),
            Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6.0)).Select(x => "hold"))
        .Skip(1);

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now));

Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second
observable1.OnNext(42);
```

That produces:

```
2017/06/30 17:04:57
2017/06/30 17:05:03
```

Change the test code to:

```
Thread.Sleep(6000); // 6 seconds
observable1.OnNext(42);
```

And you get:

```
2017/06/30 17:08:49
2017/06/30 17:08:55
```

And finally change the test code to:

```
Thread.Sleep(10000); // 10 seconds
observable1.OnNext(42);
```

And you get:

```
2017/06/30 17:09:27
2017/06/30 17:09:37
```

Let me know if that's what you want.

Could someone please edit my answer to change my code to RxJS?

Answer (score 1):

How about [`observableInstance.delay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html)?

```
observable1.delay(5000).subscribe(() => {
    alert('ok');
});
```

Comment: I updated question. This event should be fired when observable1 is fired but not earlier than 5 seconds. In your case if observable1 fired after 6 seconds then this event will fired after 11 seconds. I need 6 seconds in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Rx.js [debounceTime](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime) operator emits the most recent value from the source observable only after the specified time is elapsed.

```
Observable1.debounceTime(5000).subscribe(() => { alert('ok') } );
```